# parameters without value in bottle

Tags: python, bottle

In my hooks/routes I use:

```
debug = request.GET.get('debug', False)
```

And it works with:

```
http://test.internal.local:8888/probe?debug=anything
```

but how can I get it to work with just the flag and no value like?

```
http://test.internal.local:8888/probe?debug
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can get `debug` flag, but value would be empty string(`''`).

So check if you got that flag is simple:

```
debug = request.GET.get('debug')  # if there is no debug flag you get `None`
if debug is not None:
    # you have your debug flag
```

Comment: Great it works if I use `if debug is '':` instead of `if debug:` maybe I should change the default to ''?. Thanks

Comment: I believe it's easier to read as it is. `request.GET.get('debug')`  you know what you get(`None`) if that flag is not provided, and `if`- statement is pretty clear.